# A manga or anime from the 90s where the protagonists have gems on their forehead and their hands can burn faces. Might be vampires?

Tags: story-identification, manga, anime, horror

A manga or anime from the 90s where the protagonists have gems on their forehead and their hands can burn faces. Might be vampires?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This really doesn't have many details.  You should check the [suggestions for asking anime questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) to see if they help you recall anything else you can [edit] into your question.